# Equivalence of injectivity of a function

Tags: functions, proof-writing

A function $f:X\to Y$ is said to be injective if for all $y\in Y$ there exists at most one $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.

> The claim is: $f:X\to Y$ is injective if and only if $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ for all different $x_1,x_2\in X$.

How to proceed it? I have read the proof in [$f$ is injective if and only if for all $y \in B$ there exists at most one $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857450), and I do not understand how it can be a proof.

**Only if:**

If you suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is injective, then by definition, to each $y\in Y$ you can find at most one $x\in A$ for which $f(x)=y$. Then I look at two cases,

- For all $y\in Y$, there is no $x\in X$ for which $f(x)=y$.
- For all $y\in Y$, there is exactly one $x\in X$ for which $f(x)=y$.

If I assume the first point, it basically means that $f(x)\neq y$ for all $x\in X$ and all $y\in Y$. In particular, if $x'\in X$, then $f(x)\in Y$, and so $f(x)\neq f(x')$. But, this does not say anything about $x\neq x'$. How does this case imply that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ for all different $x_1,x_2\in X$?

If I assume the second point, it would mean that $f(x')\neq y$ for all $x'\in X$ other than $x$, because $x$ is the only element that satisfies $f(x)=y$. This is the same as saying that $f(x')\neq f(x)$ for all $x\neq x'$, as desired.

**If:**
Assume $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ for all different $x_1,x_2\in X$.

One way: Then $f(x)\neq y$ for all $x\in X$ and all $y\in Y$, which is equivalent to saying that for all $y\in Y$ there is no $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Or, another way: How do I show that there exists exactly one $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start with an actual argument. Note that "$f : X \to Y$" means that for every $x \in X, f(x)$ exists, and $f(x) \in Y$.

"$f$ is injective" means $\forall y \in Y,$ there is at most one $x \in X$ with $f(x) = Y$. "At most one" means that if $x, x' \in X$ and $f(x) = y = f(x')$, then $x = x'$. Suppose $x_1, x_2 \in X$. Let $y = f(x_1)$. As I noted above, it must be that $y \in Y$. If $f(x_2) = f(x_1) = y$, then $x_1 = x_2$. Thus $x_1, x_2$ are not different. The contrapositive is that if $x_1\ne x_2$, then $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$. So invective implies the images of distinct elements of $X$ are not equal.

Conversely, suppose for all $x_1, x_2\in X, x_1 \ne x_2 \implies f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$. Suppose there is some $y\in Y$ and $x_1, x_2 \in X$ with $f(x_1) = y = f(x_2)$. If $x_1 \ne x_2$, then $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$, a contradiction. So $x_1 = x_2$. So $y$ can only have one pre-image. I.e., there is at most one $x\in X$ with $f(x) = y$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, $f$ must be injective.

---

Now let's look at your argument. $f$ is injective means for all $y \in Y$, either

- there is no $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$, or
- there is exactly one $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$.

But you changed this to

> - For all $y\in Y$, there is no $x\in X$ for which $f(x)=y$.
> - For all $y\in Y$, there is exactly one $x\in X$ for which $f(x)=y$.

These are NOT equivalent. $\forall x,(P(x)\text{ or }Q(x))$ is not the same as $(\forall x, P(x))\text{ or }(\forall x, Q(x))$. Since for any $x \in X, f(x) \in Y$, your first condition requires $X$ to be empty. And your second condition requires $f$ to be a bijection, not just injective, because in it, you are demanding that every $y \in Y$ is $f(x)$ for some $x$.

There are lots of injective functions that do not have empty domain and are also not surjective.

> If I assume the first point, it basically means that $f(x)\neq y$ for
> all $x\in X$ and all $y\in Y$. In particular, if $x'\in X$, then
> $f(x)\in Y$, and so $f(x)\neq f(x')$.

No, it means that $X = \emptyset$, and thus there is no $x$ nor $x' \in X$. Also, for any function (injective or not) and if $x, x'$ satisfy $f(x) \ne f(x')$, that alone is enough to know that $x \ne x'$, for if $x = x'$, then $f(x) = f(x')$ simply by the definition of a function.

> How does this case imply that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ for all different $x_1,x_2\in X$?

Even in the correct version, where the "for all $y$" has not be mishandled, this case doesn't imply anything. Nor does it need to. There is no $x_1, x_2$ that correspond to $y$, by the very assumption. The case is irrelevant.

> Assume $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ for all different $x_1,x_2\in X$.
>
> One way: Then $f(x)\neq y$ for all $x\in X$ and all $y\in Y$

Then *what*? How does that follow from $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$ when $x_1 \ne x_2$?? Once again, your conclusion would only be true if $X$ was empty, as for any $x \in X, f(x) \in Y$. Therefore **there is at least one $y \in Y$ with $y = f(x)$**.

Comment: You wrote: "At most one" means that if $x,x′∈X$ and $f(x)=y=f(x′)$, then $x=x′$. May I ask where this definition comes from?

Comment: Ummm, common sense? If the two variables have a property that at most one object can have, then those two variables must both refer to that same object.